# Selenium Webdriver C# does not navigate after publishing to exe

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Writing a script that does several things for automating a web process. Everything is the code is functionally sound and works perfectly within Visual Studio. Once the code is published for distribution, the Chrome Driver seems to start but not navigate the instructions in the code.

(Things have to be omitted because it's a company intranet thing, but I can verify that everything regarding those omitted things work fine.)

Syntax:  [Here is the working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucWgc.png).

```
 public static HashSet<string> GetTestPlans(string username) 
    {
        try
        {
            ChromeOptions option = new ChromeOptions(); //Define option for chrome driver
            option.AddArgument("--headless"); //Define browser as headless
            IWebDriver Test = new ChromeDriver(); //New chrome driver

            string year = new System.DateTime().Year.ToString(); //I don't know why this is here, maybe forgot to delete
            HashSet<string> returnplanners = new HashSet<string>(); /
            HashSet<string> cleaned = new HashSet<string>(); 


            Test.Navigate().GoToUrl("<link>"); 
            IWebElement planners = Test.FindElement(By.Id("<id>")); 
            IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> plans = planners.FindElements(By.TagName("a")); 

            foreach (IWebElement i in plans) //Iterate through 
            {
                string inner = i.Text; //Convert <a> tag to string 

                returnplanners.Add(inner); //add it to hashset for drop down menu

            }
            Test.Quit(); //Exit driver 
            return returnplanners;
    }
        catch (SystemException e)
        {
            HashSet<string> returnplanners = new HashSet<string>();
            return returnplanners;
        }
```

I only included the Web driver initialization because there would be too much blacked out text to post the full program code. This is only the first used instance of using a webdriver (I was new to Selenium when I started this). I'm sure that fixing the first issue will resolve all webdriver issues

Dependencies: [A picture of the dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v1TZh.png). I believe that I have everything covered in this section. The code executes fine in Visual Studio. I included the most recent Chrome Driver at the bottom to cover the possibility that it was an out of date driver. I also tried specifically pointing to the updated driver in the initiation of the driver Ex.)`IWebDriver Test = new ChromeDriver("<Path to driver>");`which did not work either.

Actual program: [Here is a picture of the application files for the published project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syHjz.png) and [Here is the picture of the published program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RBn8.png). Finally a picture of the exported program running and stopping [on the chrome driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrvLO.png). One thing I noticed is that it is running locally, could that be the cause of the problem?

Any help is appreciated. I'm proud of this project and want to distribute it to other workers because it saves a lot of time. I couldn't find anything relating to this problem specifically on stack so forgive me if I missed something.

Comment: Is an exception happening inside the try block?

Comment: No exceptions in VS and no errors in published program

Comment: Please include your actual code in your question rather than as links to images

Comment: Is this published as a console application? Is this exe being invoked in the same computer that is running Visual Studio?

Comment: As far as I understand, it is published as a Windows Form App, and it has been tested on my computer (the one with VS) but still doesn't work outside VS

Comment: Also to clarify, the other bits of code seem to be working successfully, it's only when selenium is called is there a problem